# Displaying legends in displacement plot of Van der Pol oscillator on MATHEMATICA 8.0

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, legending, version-8

I am trying to draw different plots of Van der Pol's oscillator displacement (ListPlots and ListLinePlots) using 'Show'. I have a problem drawing the legends. Here are my codes:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
a1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[yle1Values[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps}]];

a2 = ListPlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[approx1[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps, 5}], 
   PlotMarkers -> {"o", 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red}];

a3 = ListPlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[yle11Values[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps, 
     13}], PlotMarkers -> {"\[CapitalDelta]", 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue}];

a4 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[yle111Values[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple}];

a5 = ListPlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[yle1111Values[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps, 
     5}], PlotMarkers -> {"+", 15}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];

a6 = ListPlot[
   Table[{N[Subscript[x, i]], N[yle11111Values[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Steps, 
     23}], PlotMarkers -> {"\[RightTriangle]", 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black}];

aaa = Show[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, 
  PlotLabel -> "Plots of t against y(t)", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "y(t)" }]
```

Here is my graph

[image]

Comment: 1. What version are you using? You seem to be on an older version of *Mathematica*. 2. Without definitions for the lists like `yle1Values` and `yle11111Values`, no one else will be able to evaluate your code and help you with your problem.

Comment: @  J. M. I am using Mathematica. 8.0. I employed 'yle1Values and yle11111Values' as variables. They are not definitions.

Comment: The syntax `yle1Values[[i]]` in your code implies that `yle1Values` is a list whose `i`-th element you are extracting. You have that list, but the rest of us do not.

Comment: @ J. M. That's true! It's a portion of my long code. You can make several plots yourself with the function 2 cos x. For variableness, you can make use of "2 cos x[[i]]+random numbers,{i,1,5}". Thank you.

Comment: @ J. M. yle1Values, yle11Values,... represent different results obtained by 6 various methods. So, I want to compare them on the graph. That, I have successfully done! I just want to add legends.